# How to add a Listview with SubItems

Tags: android, android-listview, subitem

I would like to display the data in an array of string as the Subitems of the listview.

How exactly could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

This is part of my code from an ap that uses fragments.  One fragment is a list fragment.

```
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Category List extends ListFragment {

final static String[] CATEGORIES = {"String1","String2",
    "String3","String4"};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
        CATEGORIES));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Download the api demos from the Android Development site or open the SDK Manager and ensure you have downloaded `Samples` for your current SDK.

Then navigate to the samples folder and take a look at `expandable lists`. There are a few fully working examples there.

On my WinXP comp the files are located here:

`C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-16\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view` then look for the `expandable lists.jar` files

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Adapter class. Here is your solution:
First create a private class in your MainActivity class like this:

```
private class Adapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<String> list;
    public Adapter(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        this.list=list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) 
    {
        return list.get(index);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup arg2) 
    {
        TextView tv_text = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        tv_text.setText(list.get(index));
        tv_text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        AbsListView.LayoutParams params = 
                new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        tv_text.setLayoutParams(params);
        tv_text.setHeight(60);
        tv_text.setTextSize(18);
        return tv_text;
    }       
}
```

then you need to put the Strings in `ArrayList<String>` :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<yourArray.length(); i++) list.add(yourArray[i]);
```

after that you need to create an instance of the Adapter class:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(list);
```

then you need to set the adapter as the main adapter of your `ListView` :

```
ListView lv_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

D